# How to pass listview into array?

Tags: vb.net

I have a ListView with 4 columns and close to 1500 rows. I want to know how to pass it to an array. I'd like the rows and columns in the ListView to match the dimensions in the array.

```
    Dim ListView1 As ListView
    ListView1 = New ListView()
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do because a `ListView` doesnt have dimensions.

Comment: Sure, with the values that I have in the list view I'd like them to be store in an array with the same format. For example: a listview with 4 columns and 100 rows would be stored in an array with the listview items stored in a 4X100 array. It would be done dynamically.

Comment: That will require a loop to copy 400 ListViewSubItems to the array; there is no "passing" the control to an array and it unpacks itself..  A *better* approach would be to put the data into a DataTable (it will BE in 4 rows x 100 cells very much like an array) then bind it to a DataGridView to display it,

Comment: I concur **^** with that guy!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the data is already in the `ListView` you could do something like this:

```
    Dim matrix(ListView1.Items.Count - 1, 3)

    For r As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim itemX = ListView1.Items(r)

        matrix(r, 0) = itemX.Text
        matrix(r, 1) = itemX.SubItems(0).Text
        matrix(r, 2) = itemX.SubItems(1).Text
        matrix(r, 3) = itemX.SubItems(2).Text
    Next
```

### UPDATE

So this is how you do it by dynamically reference columns - `Subitem`s:

```
Dim matrix(ListView1.Items.Count - 1, 3)

For r As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim itemX = ListView1.Items(r)

    matrix(r, 0) = itemX.Text ' The first item in the array 
    For c As integer = 1 To itemX.Subitems.Count
        matrix(r, c) = itemX.Subitem(c - 1).Text
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks a lot.  Could one also show how the subitems could be displayed dynamically?

Comment: Sure, I notice how you you have the rows done dynamically; how would you have the column's dynamically displayed as well? For example- if I have 4 columns for one listview and 6 for another.

Comment: Now I get it. I just updated the answer with another example. Just don't forget to accept the answer, if it satisfies your question, of course.

Comment: Sir, this is awesome. For a final step, how would one take this same array and export it to a live excel sheet? A listview with 100 rows and 4 columns for example would be 100 rows and 4 columns in Excel. Thanks

Comment: This is a whole new story :). There are numerous ways. Post another questions with details on how you going to interact with Excel - add-in, VBA, something else. But in the first place, try to do it yourself. Ask questions when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim allItems(ListView1.Items.Count-1) As ListViewItem
    ListView1.Items.CopyTo(allItems, 0)

    ' To iterate
    For Each r In allitems
         ' Row is r.index 
         For Each c In r.SubItems
            ' Text in each column is c.Text
         Next
     Next
```